# ¿Es totalmente diferente la sintaxis de SQL server y MySQL?

Tags: sql-server

He estado leyendo un libro de SQL y he aprendido cosas nuevas ,sin embargo quiero saber si las sintaxis de las consultas de sql son totalmente diferentes a las que se realizan pero en sql server,por ejemplo la sintaxis para hacer un inner join en sql es diferente o igual a la  que se utiliza en sql server.

Comment: Las consultas suelen ser prácticamente iguales en cualquier base de datos que yo conozca al menos. Te pueden cambiar los nombres de las funciones y la sintaxis a la hora de crear procedimientos almacenados o funciones.

Comment: Los gestores de bases de datos (*SGBD*) utilizan el lenguaje **SQL** para hacer, como ha dicho zeross, consultas. Por lo general lo que funciona en `SQL Server` funciona en **MySQL** pero cambiando la sintaxis o el nombre de las funciones. Por ejemplo en **SQL** para hacer un contador de un campo es `IDENTITY` y en **MySQL** es `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: si es lo que apenas he notado al parecer no es completamente diferente  la sintaxis y funciones entre ellos

Comment: SQL es un estandar (ISO/IEC 9075), lo normal es que los diferentes SGBD que implementan SQL se acojan a él por lo menos en gran medida.